# What exactly is doing the radius in Gaussian blur algorithm?

Tags: blur, gaussian, gaussianblur

Does doing a Gaussian blur on a 240*240 pixels image with radius of X will produce the same "blur" than  doing a Gaussian blur on a 100*100 pixels image with the same radius ? what exactly is doing the radius in Gaussian blur algorithm ?

often people say me it's better (more faster) to choose a lower radius on a reduced size of an image and magnify the image after. Is this true ? why ?

Answer (score 1):

see as an example 
https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10057/gaussian-blur-standard-deviation-radius-and-kernel-size
and 
http://chemaguerra.com/gaussian-filter-radius/
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks Walter. often people say me it's better (more faster) to choose a lower radius on a reduced size of an image and magnify the image after. Is this true ? why ?

Comment: Have a look at these algorithms here and check where in the loops the radius is used - you will find out that there is direct influence. http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html